# JavaScript (_.isFunction) code optimization

Tags: javascript, function, underscore.js

I needed to check an js object if is a function and i thought that this code should do it:

`typeof param === 'function'`

then i thought that checking with `_.isFunction` source code will be an good ideea.

Underscore has the `if` below wrapped arround the above check, which i'm not sure what exactly does or mean. If someone can explain this would be great. Thanks

```
// Optimize `isFunction` if appropriate.
if (typeof (/./) !== 'function') {
   ..
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In some old versions of V8, regular expressions objects had a type of `"function"` (initially, regular expressions objects were callable as functions, even if nobody used that feature).

That's why it wasn't possible to use `typeof param === 'function'` to check if a value is a function.

This isn't the case now. Use `typeof`, not `_.isFunction`, this code is obsolete.